# List items position repeating in getview

Tags: android, listview, view, baseadapter

I am creating a custom list view using baseadapter.i have 10 list item in my list.my problem is that afetr 6 items ,the first 4 are repeating.i just printed position values in getview.it gives 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3.My code is below.

thanx in advance

```
public class ProductListAdapter extends BaseAdapter  implements OnClickListener{    

/*
 * developer :sanu
 * date :10-4-2013
 * time :3.34 pm
 */
public View row;
private String[] productName;
private String[] producttype;
private String[] priceRangeFrom;
private String[] priceRangeTo;
private String[] productImage;
private Activity activity;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
static String posClicked;
ViewHolder holder;
Integer height1;
Integer width1;
Typeface tf;
Integer FirmaCount;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 
public ProductListAdapter(Activity a,String[] name,String[] type,String[] price_from,String[] price_to,String[] image,Typeface tf) {
    activity    =  a;
    productName = name;
    producttype = type;
    priceRangeFrom = price_from;
    priceRangeTo = price_to;
    productImage = image;       
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}
public int getCount() {
    return productName.length;
}
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
} 
public int getViewTypeCount (int position)
{
    return position;
}
public static class ViewHolder{
    public TextView nameProduct;
    public TextView typeProduct;
    public TextView priceRangeProduct;
    public ImageView productImage;
    public ImageView plusImage;
    public RelativeLayout mainLayout;
    public int position;  
}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {     
    if(convertView == null){            
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_list_details,parent, false);
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        holder.nameProduct =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.typeProduct =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.product);
        holder.priceRangeProduct =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pricerange);
        holder.productImage =(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        holder.plusImage =(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.dot);
        holder.mainLayout = (RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
        holder.nameProduct.setText(productName[position]);      
        if(producttype[position].length()>18)
        {
            holder.typeProduct.setText(producttype[position].substring(0,18)+"...");
        }
        else
        {
            holder.typeProduct.setText(producttype[position]);
        }
        holder.priceRangeProduct.setText(priceRangeFrom[position].substring(0,priceRangeFrom[position].length()-2)+" To "+priceRangeTo[position].substring(0, priceRangeTo[position].length()-2));          
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(productImage[position], holder.productImage);
        convertView.setTag(holder);                     
    }
    else
    {           
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

    }       
    holder.plusImage.setTag(Integer.toString(position));
    holder.plusImage.setOnClickListener(this);  
    holder.mainLayout.setTag(Integer.toString(position));
    holder.mainLayout.setOnClickListener(this); 
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: move this `holder.nameProduct.setText(productName[position]);      
        if(producttype[position].length()>18)
        {
            holder.typeProduct.setText(producttype[position].substring(0,18)+"...");
        }
        else
        {
            holder.typeProduct.setText(producttype[position]);
        }` below the last else and try

Comment: i suggest extending ArrayAdapter instead, since you can do the same action as above with less considerations

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like a case of View re-cyclcing.  Android will pass a pre-populated view to the getView method.  It does so to minimize object creation.  When an existing row-view is scrolled off screen, Android might try to recycle that view to display a row that is now on-screen.  You need to account for the fact that this view may have been used to display data for another row (which is now off screen).

You have the following line

```
holder.typeProduct.setText
```

within the following conditional:

```
if(convertView == null){
```

Move that line outside of the conditional, and all should be well.

Answer (score 3):

It's like EJK said. You are not recycling your view correctly. Change your code to this and notice where I put the setText calls

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {     
if(convertView == null){            
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_list_details,parent, false);
    holder=new ViewHolder();
    holder.nameProduct =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    holder.typeProduct =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.product);
    holder.priceRangeProduct =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pricerange);
    holder.productImage =(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    holder.plusImage =(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.dot);
    holder.mainLayout = (RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);

    convertView.setTag(holder);                     
}
else
{           
    holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

}       
    holder.plusImage.setTag(Integer.toString(position));
    holder.plusImage.setOnClickListener(this);  
    holder.mainLayout.setTag(Integer.toString(position));
    holder.mainLayout.setOnClickListener(this); 

    //setText functions are here
    holder.nameProduct.setText(productName[position]); 


    if(producttype[position].length()>18)
    {
        holder.typeProduct.setText(producttype[position].substring(0,18)+"...");
    }
    else
    {
        holder.typeProduct.setText(producttype[position]);
    }
    holder.priceRangeProduct.setText(priceRangeFrom[position].substring(0,priceRangeFrom[position].length()-2)+" To "+priceRangeTo[position].substring(0, priceRangeTo[position].length()-2));

    imageLoader.DisplayImage(productImage[position], holder.productImage);

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: on scrolling iget error on this line          holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

Comment: 11-09 15:17:39.757: E/AndroidRuntime(7145): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-09 15:17:39.757: E/AndroidRuntime(7145): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.Adapter.ProductListAdapter$ViewHolder
11-09 15:17:39.757: E/AndroidRuntime(7145):  at com.Adapter.ProductListAdapter.getView(ProductListAdapter.java:93)

Comment: 11-09 15:17:39.757: E/AndroidRuntime(7145):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1792)
11-09 15:17:39.757: E/AndroidRuntime(7145):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:676)
11-09 15:17:39.757: E/AndroidRuntime(7145):  at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:640)
11-09 15:17:39.757: E/AndroidRuntime(7145):  at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4901)

Comment: Are you sure your code is still the same as in your starting post? The first exception implies that you called convertView.setTag with a String parameter somewhere. Please make sure your code is unchanged compared to your starting post when applying my suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `getView` to

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {     
    if(convertView == null){            
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_list_details,parent, false);
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        holder.nameProduct =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.typeProduct =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.product);
        holder.priceRangeProduct =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pricerange);
        holder.productImage =(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        holder.plusImage =(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.dot);
        holder.mainLayout = (RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
        convertView.setTag(holder); 
        } else { 
         holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        } 
        holder.nameProduct.setText(productName[position]);      
        if(producttype[position].length()>18)
        {
            holder.typeProduct.setText(producttype[position].substring(0,18)+"...");
        }
        else
        {
            holder.typeProduct.setText(producttype[position]);
        }
        holder.priceRangeProduct.setText(priceRangeFrom[position].substring(0,priceRangeFrom[position].length()-2)+" To "+priceRangeTo[position].substring(0, priceRangeTo[position].length()-2));          
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(productImage[position], holder.productImage);

       holder.plusImage.setTag(Integer.toString(position));
       holder.plusImage.setOnClickListener(this);  
       holder.mainLayout.setTag(Integer.toString(position));
       holder.mainLayout.setOnClickListener(this); 
       return convertView;
}
```

Also check this

[How ListView's recycling mechanism works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works)

Comment: Thanx for your reply....but on scrolling list item i got error in           holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

Comment: @Sanu als why do you need `public int position` in view holder?

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.Adapter.ProductListAdapter$ViewHolder
om.Adapter.ProductListAdapter.getView(ProductListAdapter.java:87)
 android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2063)
android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1792)
android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:676)
11-09 12:35:29.339: E/AndroidRuntime(4245):  at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:640)

Comment: @Sanu productImage is a string array. i suggest you change it to something coz you have productImage as imageview in your holder. pls rename your variables to avoid confusion. Similarly rename others also. That would make debugging a lot simpler and help solve your problem

Comment: i just changed the imageview name.but getting the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Change getView()

Declare `ViewHolder` before `if (convertView == null)`

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_list_details,
                    parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.nameProduct = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.typeProduct = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.product);
            holder.priceRangeProduct = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.pricerange);
            holder.productImage = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.image);
            holder.plusImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dot);
            holder.mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }
        holder.nameProduct.setText(productName[position]);
        if (producttype[position].length() > 18) {
            holder.typeProduct.setText(producttype[position].substring(0, 18)
                    + "...");
        } else {
            holder.typeProduct.setText(producttype[position]);
        }
        holder.priceRangeProduct.setText(priceRangeFrom[position].substring(0,
                priceRangeFrom[position].length() - 2)
                + " To "
                + priceRangeTo[position].substring(0,
                        priceRangeTo[position].length() - 2));
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(productImage[position], holder.productImage);
        holder.plusImage.setTag(Integer.toString(position));
        holder.plusImage.setOnClickListener(this);
        holder.mainLayout.setTag(Integer.toString(position));
        holder.mainLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.Adapter.ProductListAdapter$ViewHolder om.Adapter.ProductListAdapter.getView(ProductListAdapter.java:87) android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2063) android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1792) android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:676) 11-09 12:35:29.339: E/AndroidRuntime(4245): at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:640)

Comment: @Sanu can you tell me in which line the error is pointing. share that line of code.

Comment: holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();